# Laravel Eloquent left join query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have like this query which work in plain sql:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, roles.name
FROM users
LEFT JOIN model_has_roles ON model_has_roles.model_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN roles ON roles.id = model_has_roles.role_id
ORDER BY roles.name ASC
```

Using laravel I tried like this but it's doesn't work:

```
$user = $request->user();

$role = (array) $request->get('role', []);
$order = (array) $request->get('order');

$perPage = $request->get('perPage') ?? 10;

$users = User::where('id', '!=', $user->id);

if(count($role)) {
    if (($key = array_search('admin', $role)) !== false) {
        unset($role[$key]);
    }
    $users = $users->whereHas('roles', function ($query) use($role) {
        return $query->whereIn('name', $role);
    });
} else {
    $users = $users->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
        return $query->whereIn('name', ['farmer', 'specialist', 'company']);
    });
}

if(count($order) && isset($order['field'])) {
    $orderType = $order['type'] ?? 'ASC';
    if($order['field'] == 'role') {
        $users = $users->leftJoin('model_has_roles', 'model_has_roles.model_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.role_id')
        ->orderBy('roles.name', $orderType);
    } else {
        $users = $users->orderBy($order['field'], $orderType);
    }
}

$users = $users->paginate($perPage);
```

Error message:

```
`"message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` left join `model_has_roles` on` `model_has_roles`.`model_id` = `users`.`id` left join `roles` on `roles`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`role_id` where `id` != 3 and exists (select * from `roles` inner join `model_has_roles` on `roles`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`role_id` where `users`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`model_id` and `model_has_roles`.`model_type` = App\\Models\\User and `name` in (specialist, company)))",
```

Comment: `$users->leftJoin` - where's the first definition of `$users`?

Comment: the error shows where `id` != 3 but you didn't show us the whole query.

Comment: Where is `and `name` in (specialist, company)` in your query?

Comment: Question updated @HoneyBadger

Comment: $users = User::where('id', '!=', $user->id); change to $users = User::where('users.id', '!=', $user->id);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your both models have id and after sql execute the query id column will be ambiguous so this will help you:

```
$users = User::where('id', '!=', $user->id);
```

**change to**

```
$users = User::where('users.id', '!=', $user->id);
```

**Then try:**

```
$users = $users->select(['users.id', 'users.name', 'roles.name'])
                ->leftJoin('model_has_roles', 'model_has_roles.model_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.role_id')
                ->orderBy('roles.name', 'ASC');
```